# EF6 IN clause on specific properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Good morning,

I'm having trouble with a EF query. This is what i am trying to do.

First i am pulling a list of ID's like so (List of IDs are found in the included x.MappingAccts entity):

```
Entities.DB1.Mapping mapping = null;
using (var db = new Entities.DB1.DB1Conn())
{
    mapping = db.Mappings.Where(x => x.Code == code).Include(x => x.MappingAccts).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Later, i'm trying to do a query on a different DB against the list of Id's i pulled above (essentially a IN clause):

```
using (var db = new Entities.DB2.DB2Conn())
{
    var accounts = db.Accounts.Where(mapping.MappingAccts.Any(y => y.Id == ?????????)).ToList();
}
```

As you can see i only got part way with this.

Basically what i need to do is query the Accounts table against it's ID column and pull all records that match mapping.MappingAccts.Id column.

Most of the examples i am finding explain nicely how to do this against a single dimension array but i'm looking to compare specific columns.

Any assist would be awesome.

Nugs

Answer (score 1):

An IN clause is generated using a `IEnumerable.Contains`.

From the first DB1 context, materialize the list of Id's

```
var idList = mapping.MappingAccts.Select(m => m.Id).ToList();
```

Then in the second context query against the materialized list of id's

```
var accounts = db.Accounts
                 .Where(a => idList.Contains(a.Id))
                 .ToList();
```

The only problem you may have is with the amount of id's you are getting in the first list. You may hit a limit with the SQL query.

Comment: yes.  that's why i materialize a list of id's not linked to the first dbcontext.  Then do a Contains on that.

Comment: Sorry, I realized right after making the comment that you had it handled. I tried to delete the comment before you replied, but you were too fast.

Comment: @BradleyUffner No problem.  i edited the answer for better clarity.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't use this method as there are other properties i need access to in mapping.MappingAccts

Comment: Depending on the size of you data, you can materialize both sides and join them in memory using linq.

Answer (score 0):

This will give the list of Accounts which have the Ids contained by MappingAccts

```
using (var db = new Entities.DB2.DB2Conn())
{
    var accounts = db.Accounts.Where(s => mapping.MappingAccts.Any(y => y.Id == s.Id)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I get the following error using this method: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Entities.DB1.MappingAcct'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.